# ¿Cómo evitar escribir una letra con python?

Tags: python

estoy programando un bot en python, pero tengo un problema con el código

Al escribir una sola letra me recoge todas las imagenes y no deberia hacer esto, deberia de darme un error "El aumento no existe!"
[image]

Al escribir el titulo correcto: Subidón máximo
Deberia de aparecer asi:
[image]

Este es mi código que estoy usando:

```
import json
import requests

args = input("Escribe: ")


response = requests.get("https://jose89fcb.es/api/aumentos.php")
data = response.json()

match_found = False

for api in data['augments']:
    if args in api["name"]:

        print(f'{api["icon"]}')
      
        

        match_found = True
    

if not match_found:
     print("El aumento no existe!")
```

¿Cómo podria solucionar este problema?

Muchas gracias antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El "fallo" se produce en la línea:

```
if args in api["name"]
```

Ya que se está comprobando si la subcadena "a" (valor de `args`) está presente en la cadena `api["name"]`, lo que se evalúa como `True` siempre que el valor de `api["name"]` contenga una "a" (que no son todos los casos como afirmas en el enunciado).

Debes cambiar el operador a usar en la comparación, por ejemplo:

```
if args == api["name"]
```

Comment: Va por ahi.. pero ahora, va a tener que poner el nombre exacto...

Comment: @gbianchi por su descripción, es lo que quiere

Comment: Sin saber las necesidades del problema es dificil proponer soluciones. Se podrían comparar las cadenas en minúsculas (`args.lower() == api["name"].lower()`) o hacer uso por ejemplo de la función `get_close_matches()` de la librería `difflib` para evitar tener que poner el nombre exacto